# How to add Custom Attention Layer for Seq2Seq in keras with different timesteps for encoder and decoder

Tags: keras, attention-model

I am trying to implement attention layer  in seq2seq in keras. I am using this code for my implemention: https://github.com/datalogue/keras-attention/blob/master/models/custom_recurrents.py, but it seems that  it assumes that both the encoder and decoder have the same timesteps, but in my implementation I require them to be different.  Can anyone guide me how this can be done.

Thanks